# What data does admob collect for iOS?

Tags: admob, app-store-connect

I already know the answer to this but I'm asking because it took me a few hours to find it and want to make this easily available for others.

As of December 8, 2020, Apple has made it mandatory for developers to release what data is being collected and what it's being used for. If developers don't comply, they won't be able to publish new apps or release updates for current apps.

**So the question is**: What data does Google Admob collect and how does it use it?

Comment: Thanks for posting. I found an article that discusses this for iOS dev as well: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/filling-out-the-app-privacy-section-in-app-store-connect-for-admob-users-bca0768ad86e

Comment: Definitely more detailed than my answer. I'll update it with that resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is Google's official [source](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/data-disclosure) when it comes to this topic. It's also where most of this answer will be coming from. I would recommend taking a look at it and checking back with it for updates.

As of now, there are about 6 types of data Admob collects and uses:

- IP address, which may be used to estimate the general location of a device.
- Non-user related crash logs, which may be used to diagnose problems and improve the SDK. Diagnostic information may also be used for advertising and analytics purposes.
- User-associated performance data such as app launch time, hang rate, or energy usage, which may be used to evaluate user behavior, understand the effectiveness of existing product features, and plan new features. Performance data may also be used for displaying ads, including sharing with other entities that display ads.
- A Device ID such as the device's advertising identifier or other app-bounded device identifiers, which may be used for the purpose of third-party advertising and analytics.
- Advertising data, such as advertisements the user has seen, may be used to power analytics and advertising features.
- Other user product interactions like app launch taps, and interaction information, like video views, may be used to improve advertising performance.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @GeneCode for a more detailed [source](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/filling-out-the-app-privacy-section-in-app-store-connect-for-admob-users-bca0768ad86e). It goes more in-depth than my answer which only covers the basics. Also wish I had found this at the time. It would have been very helpful!

Comment: That git connected article is well written and more detailed, but I am not sure if it is accurate. We don't really know if adMob is linking user's IP address to their personal identity. This could be true but it is also possible that they do not. Looking at some of the top games in the App Store which are littered with ads have disclosed that "data is NOT linked to you". so declaring otherwise may make your app look like spyware..